# UN AUTHORIZE ENDPOINT

Tags: salesforce

In salesforce, I am trying to call an external system and I'm receiving the following error:

```
System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint.
```

**Note:** I have already specified the end point in remote site settings.

```
 string ApplicationID='****';
String ApplicationKey = '*****';
  string companyId;
 string languageId;
//For Getting session id
wwwViadComSecurityV2.BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService s=new 
wwwViadComSecurityV2.BasicHttpBinding_IAuthenticationService();
    wwwViadComSecurityV2.AppSessionInfo 
  a=s.StartAppSession(ApplicationID,ApplicationKey,companyId,languageId);
   system.debug('>>>>>>>>>>'+a.sessionID);
```

Comment: Where is your code? How can we help you without it?

Comment: check edited code

Comment: The tag which you used quite clearly states: ***A Platform-as-a-Service development environment delivered on Salesforce.com - the platform is more correctly referred to as Force.com. A dedicated Salesforce Stack Exchange is available for all your Salesforce questions at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint in your remote site setting must match exactly that used in your Callout.  Http is different than Https.  The subdomain must be the same too.  You should add a line in your code to debug the endpoint of the web service you are calling.